# How to use if else condition with variable in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs. Right now I am getting the current `url/hostname`. Now I want to use this URL with an if-else condition, which means I just want if `url="/"`(home page) then the first header should display otherwise second word should display. In other words, I want to know how we can use if-else condition with dynamic variable?
Here is my current code

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const Header = () => {
const router = useRouter();
const url =router.asPath;


return (
    <>
    <div>
        //need to use if else condition based on "url" variable 
    </div>
   </>
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ternary operators` there to render based on a condition, like this:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const Header = () => {
const router = useRouter();
const url = router.asPath;

return (
    <>
    <div>
        {url === "something" ? <Foo /> : <Bar />}
    </div>
   </>
    )
}
```

Comment: giving me following error
"ReferenceError: url is not defined"

Comment: I have updated the answer.  It will work now.  Issue was due to one closing braces before return statement. I just copied your code and improvised it,  didn't checked the code. It came from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const Header = () => {
const router = useRouter();
const url = router.asPath;

return (
    <>
    <div>
        {url === "smth" ? <First /> : <Second />}
    </div>
   </>
    )
}

return (
    <>
    <div>
        {url === "smth" && <First />}
        {url === "smth" && <Second />}
    </div>
   </>
    )
}
```

You use both methods